# Has LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation been removed in Spring-Boot 1.4.1

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a SpringBoot application running with Hibernate 5 to take advantage of the Java LocalDate changes I believe it includes (rather than using java.util.Date).

To get newer Hibernate I moved to Spring 1.4.1.RELEASE in my Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.4.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker':1.4.1.RELEASE")
compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version:'1.4.191'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.1'
compile group: 'org.sitemesh', name: 'sitemesh', version:'3.0.1'
```

After some unfortunate issues with getting dependencies loading properly (IDE caching etc) when I run up my SpringBoot application I get the following error:

```
2016-10-25 10:40:36.798 ERROR 7448 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitRootLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

I'm suspecting that either some library hasn't updated correctly or I'm missing something in my dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies look fine. Please check if "spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar" is available after you build your project in IDE. Try to cleanup your maven repository and rebuild project. If you are using Eclipse then you can use Maven > Update Project option.

Comment: I went through several clean/install/update/cache clearing cycles, eventually the issue went away. Not really sure exactly what fixed it!

I suspect it was a result of changing versions of libraries and newer/older versions not being replaced properly in the build process for some reason or the IDE keeping a ref to version different to gradle file.